# How to store leading zero in csv in order to pass postman script

Tags: javascript, csv, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I am running scripts which compares API response with values from CSV file,

Undelying CUSIP Number 1 | AssertionError: expected '24936205' to deeply equal '024936205'

I receive above error as i am not able to store leading 0 in csv.
Any suggestions?

Note - I tried changing the format of cell to text and added 0 in front but when i close leading zero disappears.

Comment: just righ click the column and  click format and set column format as text before savingexcel file

Comment: Could you add the code

Answer (score 0):

Open the CSV file with MS Excel. Use the excel formula to format the cell.
Say I want five-digit number with leading zero for a four-digit number.

You can use like this in excel.

```
 =TEXT(A2,”00000″)
```

After changing the values, copy the same cell and paste as values. This should work.

Comment: I used the formula and it does add leading zero but when i run script it fails with same error.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the numbers as text/values after conversion?

Comment: i tried that and it shows me as text but after closing and running through postman it still not treats as text.

Comment: I found that it was a postman issue. Fix will be changing the value in CSV as a string. Eg. "024936205". Reference [Link](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2734)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my requests to work, by adding a couple of lines to the pre-request script (My variable is always the same length, hence the if):

```
var policyno = data['PolicyNo'].toString()
if(policyno.length < 12){
   policyno = '0'+ policyno
   pm.variables.set("PolicyNo",policyno)
}
```

this works with CSV data.